# Qualtrics header works for first page only

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm trying to include equations in my Qualtrics survey using LaTex, so I'm using MathJax.  I've hincluded the following in the header so that it runs through all the pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

This works great... but only for the first page when preview the whole survey!  However, I can see the equations displayed on the other pages if I preview the question individually.

Someone else also had this issue with javascript in the header and resolved it by having no transition effects between the pages. I've tried this, but it doesn't solve my problem (although their script to suppress the Qualtrics logo at the bottom of each page worked for my survey by changing the transitions to none).

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 3):

I thought this was a Qualtrics issue, but more of a MathJax rendering issue.

This was asked elsewhere under tags, and I found a solution.

By adding the following in my header, all was fixed... for now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(
  ["resetEquationNumbers",MathJax.InputJax.TeX],
  ["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]
);
</script>
```